# write new id3v2-tags in mp3-headers (actionscript-3)

Tags: actionscript-3, metadata, id3, id3-tag

Hello is it possible to write new id3v2 tags to a mp3-file through actionscript?
Normally you can read/write tags like artist,album,genre...
But I would like to add for example the tag "atmosphere = smooth".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no working library to write/edit ID3 tags in ActionScript, or at least I wouldn't know of one.
But you can access and edit the file as [ByteArray](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html). Check the [ID3v2.3 specification](http://www.id3.org/id3v2.3.0) to find out which bytes to read and write.

There *is* a c/c++ project called [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) on sourceforge.  Should you consider porting this to ActionScript using [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/), I would be very much interested in the resulting product ;)

Comment: There are some libraries with the attempt to access id3 tags in actionscript: http://code.google.com/p/mp3infoutil/ and http://code.google.com/p/metaphile/ and http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=3but I will have to try those first and I will post here if I will have to port it.